# Javascript: Assigning a boolean property through variable is not working

Tags: javascript, rgraph

I want to convert string variable to boolean.

when i am assigning a properties without variable it is working:

```
.Set( 'bevel', false )  // working
```

now i want to assign this via variable like this:

```
function abc(prop){

.Set( 'bevel', prop )  // not working
.Set( 'bevel', Boolean(prop) )  // this is also not working
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var prop = 'true';` should be unquoted

```
var prop = true;
```

Using boolean with string it would return true for both as if it is string and containing string results in true

```
Boolean('true');//true
Boolean('false');//true
```

Comment: what if it was passed through like parameter ? 

function abc(prop){
.Set( 'bevel', prop )
}

Comment: sorry i have edited my question again check it please

Answer (score 1):

`true` is a string here:

```
var prop = 'true';
```

Should be

```
var prop = true;
```

Comment: what if it was passed through like parameter ? 

function abc(prop){
.Set( 'bevel', prop )
}

Comment: It always depends on what you pass as parameter, if it's `'true'` it will match strings, if it's `true` it will match booleans.